# How can I access data db in my controller

Tags: database, zend-framework, controller

I retrieved the last comment from my db and I want to compare to that comment which is getting posted. 
( I have a method that retrive the last comment ) but my problem is I don't know how to access that comment in my controller. 
 I did like this:

```
// instantiation call goes here
$lastCmmt = method call goes here
if( $last[0]['body_com'] != $cmmtForm->getValues('cmt'){

  //saving new comment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's some pretty nasty pseudo code you've got there.
Anyway, by default, Zend Framework doesn't come with a typical 'Model' layer as you may be used to with other MVC frameworks, so how you call the model from the controller is entirely up to you.

You can do things the fancy way by creating a model getter and using it like this `$this->getModel('Comment')->get($id);` but to start with, just do something like this

```
$model   = new Model_Comment;
$comment = $model->get($id);

// ...compare
```

Comment: hello im using this site for the first time so sorry for my ignorance , infact im retrieving only one row but my problem is how to get access to a coloumn in my controller so ican compare ??

Comment: You need to setup a model class for your comments, and how you set them up and use from inside the controller is up to you.

In your model, create a method get() to do your Zend_Db_Table fetchRow() call and return the result. Call that method from the controller and do your comparison.

Comment: well this what i've in my model  `$select = $this->select()
          ->from(array('c'=>'commentaires'))
          ->order(array('id DESC','id')) 
          ->limit('1') ;
        $select = $select->query() ;  
        $row = $select->fetchAll() ;
        return $row`  but i dont kno how to get the comment column in my controller ;P

Comment: Ok, I'm assuming you have that code in a public method inside your model. From inside your controller, just do `$model = new Model_ClassName; $comment = $model->methodName();`. One thing I've found with some MVC developers is that for some reason they seem to forget that at the end of the day, controllers and models are simply native classes and can be used as such; you _don't_ need framework 'automagic' for everything!

Comment: great  now in that $commentvariable how can i get the db columns ??  thanks. by the way even i do 2 spaces i dont go to the next line why ?? thanks again

Comment: $comment is whatever you return from your model method, so in your case you return the result of $select->fetchAll();. If you check the docs, fetchAll() will return an array of data like `array('id' => 1, 'comment' => 'This is my comment')` etc. Its just an array.

Comment: In that case, if you're trying to access just one row, do `$select->fetch();` instead of `$select->fetchAll();`. Really, documentation is your friend http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html